# How to always redirect to the main domain?

Tags: .net, iis-6

I have multiple domains that redirect to the same website. Example www.abc.com and www.def.com both redirect to www.abc.com. What I want is even if user types www.def.com in the browser address bar it should show www.abc.com in the browser bar.

My website is in .NET and hosted on IIS6.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a rewriting tool such as Ionics - http://iirf.codeplex.com/.

Alternatively you could write some code that detects the domain and redirects with the right response code, a 302 is best for seo.